# Wpf: Get image added to dll solution thru the plugin's property

Tags: wpf, image, resources

App has plugins support. Each plugin (DLL) has image of png type just added to solution (currently build action is 'Content', see the pic). Each plugin implements an interface, one of the property of the interface is intended to be an image representation, e.g. 'Icon' property. I would like to load plugins, and display an image on the toolbox for each of the plugin thru that property.

[image]

```
public interface ISomePlugin {
   GetSomeImageTypeDontKnowWhat Icon { get;  }
}

[Export(typeof(ISomePlugin))]
internal SomePlugin : ISomePlugin 
{
    public GetSomeImageTypeDontKnowWhat Icon {
        ...
        return GetSomeImageTypeDontKnowWhat;
    }
}
```

And then I want (for example) somehow assign that image to some WPF control content from code behind

```
// just loaded a plugin thru MEF
btn1.Content = plugin.Icon;
```

P.S. Sorry for so stupidly explained question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution by myself, added the image to resources file. Please, could you review and say is it correct approach? Shouldn't there be memory leaks problems?

1. Created to a plugin dll project 'New Item...' > 'Resource File' (called 'Settings.resx')
2. Added a png image to that resource file as 'Add Existing File...'.
3. Implemented plugin's interface property 'Icon' of Image type as:

   ```
   public Image Icon { get
   {
       Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
       Settings.icon.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
       stream.Position = 0;
       byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
       stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);
       BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
       bitmapImage.BeginInit();
       bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
       bitmapImage.EndInit();
       return new Image { Source = bitmapImage };
   } }
   ```
4. Now in the plugin consumer code I use the return value as

   ```
   // load and enumerate plugins code
   btn1.Content = plugin.Icon;
   ```